# SSRS parameter issue for checking multiple condition

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I am passing a date parameter and in SSRS Dataset Filters I am filtering the tasks whose created date is below the parameter passed  date

```
=cdate(Fields!WI_CreatedDate.Value)
>=
= (Parameters!SinceDate.Value)
```

If I want to check the condition for task Closed date & tasked resolved date, then How can I mention it in the parameter or there is any other way around ?

Condition should be like

```
Sincedate <= (CreatedDate or Closed date or Resolved date)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to handle this by using an `IIf` expression to perform the check and return a pass/fail condition, something like:

```
=IIf(Parameters!Sincedate.Value <= Fields!CreatedDate.Value
    or Parameters!Sincedate.Value <= Fields!ClosedDate.Value
    or Parameters!Sincedate.Value <= Fields!ResolvedDate.Value
  , true
  , false)
```

Set this as a boolean filter to show when the expression = `true`.

This way it will display rows that fulfil at least one of the checked.

Comment: It worked...Thanks. Little modification done for date conversion